# .htaccess denies files to download from script

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

Good day all,

I have a folder called documents in my site root, this is password protected by a .htpasswd file, but it is allowed to be accessed by a script to view.

how would I allow a script to be able to download the file without accessing it directly from the directory?

I'll give an example to explain the situation.

on my home page I display the picture test.jpg, this image is in the documents folder that is protected. The image displays correctly on the home page.

If type in the address bar www.domain.com/documents/test.jpg it does not display or downloads, but asks for a password.(this I want, but don’t want people to type in a password for each file they want to download)

Is there a way that I can make php or JavaScript download the document without ever having to prompt for a password? Other words bypass the .htaccess rule?

thanx in advance

Comment: The htaccess is processed before any PHP is, so bypassing it is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I've retagged adding PHP and Javascript. There is nothing stopping you writing a remapper PHP script which is outside the documents folder and therefore accessible without Apache authentication.  This could issue a [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to send the file (see the document example and user contributions for a more detailed explanation.  Since this is a server-side script, it will have direct access to the protected directory.

Of course you might want to implement some form of access control, say appending a request parameter **check** which is based on the md5 of the filename plus a shared secret.  This would be easy to compute in the calling script.  However, once you move such access negotiation to a client-side script you need to accept that this could be retro-engineered and exploited by any experienced hacker.

As a footnote, if you want to allow users to download your images, why are locating them in an access controlled directory.  Why not just move them out of this directory?

Answer (score 1):

As Barry said, the .htaccess is processed before any PHP is, so bypassing it is not an option. You will have to either change the .htaccess configuration or write a remapper PHP script.

I suggest changing the .htaccess configuration to allow direct download links but deny directory listing. This will allow people to download direct links such as `http://www.example.com/documents/some-file-name.ext` without being prompted for a password, but they will have to know the link ahead of time - they won't be able to view the `/documents/` folder to see everything in there.

You can do this by commenting out or removing the Auth directives:

```
#AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpassword
#AuthName "Name"
#AuthType Basic
#Require Valid-User
```

And adding a directive to block directory listing:

```
Options -Indexes
```